# Joda-Time: DateTime, DateMidnight and LocalDate usage

Tags: java, datetime, interface, jodatime

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library includes different datetime classes

> [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) - Immutable replacement
>   for JDK Calendar
>  [DateMidnight](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateMidnight.html)
>   - Immutable class representing a date where the time is forced to
>   midnight
>  [LocalDateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html) -
>   Immutable class representing a local
>   date and time (no time zone)

I'm wondering how are you using these classes in your *Layered Applications*.

I see advantages in having almost all the Interfaces using LocalDateTime (at the Service Layer at least) so that my Application doesn't have to manage Timezones and can safely assume Times always in UTC. My app could then use DateTime to manage Timezones at the very beginning of the Execution's Flow.

I'm also wondering in which scenario can DateMidnight be useful.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

> I see advantages in having almost all
> the Interfaces using LocalDateTime (at
> the Service Layer at least) so that my
> Application doesn't have to manage
> Timezones and can safely assume Times always in UTC.

I'm not sure I understand your line of thinking here. `LocalDateTime` and `DateTime` represent two quite different concepts. It's not the case that a `LocalDateTime` has some implicit UTC timezone: it actually has *no* timezone (internally it may be represented as a `DateTime` with UTC timezone, but it's just an implementation detail, it does not matter to the programmer who uses it).

[You can see in the API docs](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_instant.html) that, while a **`DateTime`** is an "**`Instant`**" (a point in the world time line, a physical concept), a **`LocalDateTime`** is NOT such a thing. The `LocalDateTime` is actually a [**`Partial`**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_partial.html), (a "civil" concept), in a different class hierarchy. The class names might -unfortunately- make you think that `LocalDateTime` is some specialization of `DateTime`: well, it isn't.

A **`LocalDateTime`** should be regarded as a pair {**`Date`** (`Y/M/D`) ; **`Time`** (`hh:mm:ss.msec`)}, a bunch of numbers which corresponds to the "civil" standard representation of time-related data. If we are given a `LocalDateTime`, we cannot convert it directly to a `DateTime`, we need to specify a timezone; and that conversion takes us to another kind of entity. (An analogy: Strings and byte streams in Java: to convert between them, you must specify a charset encoding, because they are conceptually different things)

When to use one or the other in the application... it's sometimes arguable, but frequently it's clear enough once the Jodatime concepts are understood. And IMO is not much related to "layers", perhaps more to use cases or scenarios.

A non-trivial -borderline- example: You work at Google, programming the Calendar. You must let the user manage (add, see, modify) an event which includes a date-time (lets ignore recurrent events), say "*I have an appointment with my doctor on 2019-July-3 at 10:00 am*". What is the time-date entity to use in the software layer (for *this usecase*)? I'd say: a `LocalDateTime`. Because the user is not really dealing with a physical point in time, but with a civil time: the date and time that displays the clock in his wrist or in his home. He does not even think of timezones (lets ignore the special case of a user who is traveling around the world...) Then, in the business and presentation layer, a `LocalDateTime` seems the right entity.

But suppose that you must also code a different scenario: a reminder. When the Google internal scheduler detects that the event stored by the user is N minutes in the future from now, it must send him a reminder. Here, "*N minutes from now*" is a totally "physical" concept of time, so here the "business layer" would deal with a `DateTime`. There are several alternatives, for example: the event was stored in the DB as a `LocalDateTime` (ie. just time and date without timezone - one frequently uses a UTC timestamp to represent that, but this is an implementation detail). In this scenario (only in this), we must load it as a `DateTime`, we convert it using a Timezone, probably from the user's profile.

Comment: DateMidnight was a bad idea and is now deprecated

Comment: Instead of the `midnight`-related classes and methods (all deprecated), see the new method [`DateTime::withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay--).

Comment: @NickSiderakis That method [`DateTime::withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay--) usually means the time `00:00:00.000`. But not always because of Daylight Saving Time and possibly other anomalies.

Comment: I always found flight status illustrates use of both `LocalDateTime` and `DateTime` quite nicely. When you look for a flight on Google, say [BA005](https://www.google.de/search?q=BA005) (LHR-NRT), it will give you local times for departure and arrival: 13:50, and 10:35 the next day, respectively - but the flight doesn't take 20h45, because [10:35 Tokyo time in GMT](https://www.google.de/search?q=10%3A35+tokyo+time+in+gmt) is actually 01:35 GMT (the next day). The trip thus takes 11h45. Internally, the flight status might use `DateTime` (zoned), but it might only expose the `LocalDateTime`...

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by leonbloy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658607/642706) is correct and vitally important. I am merely translating to the java.time classes that replace the Joda-Time project.

## java.time

### Specific moment

For a specific moment on the timeline:

- Always in UTC is represented by [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html).
- Assigned an offset-from-UTC is represented by [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).
- Assign a full time zone rather than mere offset is represented by [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

These all replace the `Instant` & `DateTime` class in Joda-Time. These java.time classes all have a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) versus the milliseconds used by Joda-Time.

### Midnight versus Start-of-day

For midnight, the Joda-Time project concluded “midnight” is a vague and unproductive concept. The midnight-related classes and midnights were all deprecated in later versions of Joda-Time, replaced with the practical concept of “first moment of the day”.

The java.time classes took the same lesson, using a "first moment of the day" approach. Look for `atStartOfDay` methods on java.time classes such as `LocalDate`.

Never assume a day starts at 00:00. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) mean the day may start at other times such as 01:00.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = 
    LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.MARCH , 12 )                    // Instantiate a date-only value without time zone.
             .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/Havana" ) ) ;  // Cuba jumps from 00:00 to 01:00 on Spring DST cut-over.
```

For example, see how Cuba starts the day at 1 AM on their Spring DST cut-over.

> zdt: 2017-03-12T01:00-04:00[America/Havana]

### Unzoned

For representing the vague idea of possible moments over a range of about 26-27 hours but not an actual moment on the timeline, use `LocalDateTime`. This class purposely lacks any offset-from-UTC or time zone.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 23 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 0 ) ;
```

If your business context implies a specific time zone, you can apply it to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;  // Determine a specific point on timeline by providing the context of a time zone.
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).