# Round down a DateTime based on a given Period using Joda-Time

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

Given a period such as 3 days, or 5 weeks (a period with only one field type), I want to round a given `DateTime` to the nearest unit of that period (i.e, ignore the 5 in '5 days'). Examples:

Example 1:

- **Period:** 3 days.
- **DateTime:** Wednesday 4:26 AM UTC          (2013-05-15T04:26:00Z)
- **Rounded DateTime:** Wednesday Midnight UTC (2013-05-15T00:00:00Z)

Example 2:

- **Period:** 5 weeks.
- **DateTime:** Wednesday 4:26 AM UTC (2013-05-15T04:26:00Z)
- **Rounded DateTime:** Monday Midnight UTC (2013-05-13T00:00:00Z)

My initial idea was to use `Period`'s `DurationFieldType getFieldTypes()` method, and for every matching field in a `DateTime` (below the largest field), set them to zero. However, I don't know how to get the `DateTimeFieldType`s from a `DateTime` and how to compare them to a `DurationFieldType`.

I would prefer not to do a huge `if else` approach.

Answer (score 1):

Example bellow is a solution in case you can express period in days (can be modified to weeks, months etc.). Using DateTime Joda Java Library.

Unfortunately with rounding you require I see possible issue. You need to have a starting point in time since when you calculate the periods. In example bellow we calculate periods since 1970/01/01 00:00:00 UTC. Or are you actually asking to get period of 3 days from first day of a month (year) etc? It would make more sense.

Questions you need to ask your self: What will happen on leap days?

Java Method

```
DateTime roundDays(DateTime dt, int windowDays) {
    Duration p = Duration.standardDays(windowDays);

    long t = dt.getMillis() / p.getMillis() * p.getMillis();
    // Keep TimeZone and round floor to a day
    return new DateTime(t, dt.getZone()).dayOfMonth().roundFloorCopy();
}
```

Example use:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1385578964580L, DateTimeZone.UTC);

System.out.println(roundDays(dt, 3));
System.out.println(roundDays(dt.plusDays(2), 3));
System.out.println(roundDays(dt.plusDays(4), 3));
System.out.println(roundDays(dt.plusDays(6), 3));

// Prints data rounded to every 3 days
// 2013-11-26T00:00:00.000Z
// 2013-11-29T00:00:00.000Z
// 2013-11-29T00:00:00.000Z
// 2013-12-02T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: I was able to take your example and round minutes and it works great. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comment:

It's not clear what that "rounding" means. To start with, you should deal with `LocalDateTime`s, not with `DateTime`s (they are very different things, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538448/joda-time-datetime-datemidnight-and-localdate-usage/2658607#2658607) ).

It seems to me you want to set to zero all fields with resolution lower than that of your "period" unit, and then set the next field to a multiple of the given value... is that so? Then, I don't understand your second example (where are the 5 weeks?), and anyway, that would be badly specified: what to do with a period of "40 months" ?

Comment: Yes, I found it hard to express my problem. You understand perfectly. A period of 40 months would be exactly the same as 1 month. I shall investigate using `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: But, again, would you mind explain how you get 2013-05-13 for "5 weeks" ? Are you counting week in year and are you picking the nearest multiple of 5?

Comment: I only care about the unit 'weeks', and I round down the given `DateTime` to the start of the closest week. Same with 40 months, I want to round down to the closest month (from the given `DateTime`). I have to accept periods such as 40 months, but only the `month` part is needed for this calculation.